# control fan speed using Applescript (or terminal)

Tags: terminal, applescript, hardware

I would like to control the fan speed using terminal, if possible without third party app.

The idea is to automate and schedule different fan speed.

Comment: The third party apps must set or change some values - have you found out where these are stored?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lubbofancontrol/ might give you some ideas.  Or http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/299811-readsmc-for-efi-a-tool-to-enter-read-smc-keys-from-efi-shell-on-real-macs/  Or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304678/reading-out-the-smc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS does not support user control of the fan speed.

### smcFanControl

The open source project [smcFanControl](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl) claims to offer fan speed control. Be careful overriding Apple's fan behaviour; you risk damaging your computer.